# How do I put all prime numbers into an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, primes

I already have the code that checks for prime numbers but can't figure out how to make array. The code below can count how many primes are there in an interval

```
#include <stdio.h>
int primeChecker(int n);
int main(){
    int x, y, i, flag, count=0, *primes;

    //primes = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int)*count);

    printf("Enter two positive integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("Prime numbers between %d and %d are: ", x, y);
    for(i = x + 1; i < y; ++i) {

        // flag will be equal to 1 if i is prime
        flag = primeChecker(i);

        if(flag == 1){
            printf("%d ", i);
            count = count+1;

        }//if
    }//for

    return 0;
}//main

// user-defined function to check prime number
int primeChecker(int n){
    int j, flag = 1;
    for(j = 2; j <= n / 2; ++j) {
        if(n % j == 0) {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }//if
    }//for
    return flag;
}//primeChecker
```

Comment: You seem to know about `malloc`. Now try to think about a function to ***realloc**ate* memory.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have attached is finding the prime numbers perfectly so all that is left to do is to store the number in an array as soon as it is found, for that first you have to declare an array which can either be done statically like this :-

```c
int arr[size_of_array]
```

or dynamically using malloc like this :-

```c
ptr = (int*)malloc((size_of_array) * sizeof(int));
```

then as soon as you find a number, put it in the array you have created ( you can use count to keep track of index of the array )

```c
arr[count] = i;
```

so after all the alterations you code should look like this :-

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int primeChecker(int n);
int main(){
    int x, y, i, flag, count=0, *primes;

    //primes = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int)*count);
    int arr[100];
    printf("Enter two positive integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("Prime numbers between %d and %d are: ", x, y);
    for(i = x + 1; i < y; ++i) {

        // flag will be equal to 1 if i is prime
        flag = primeChecker(i);

        if(flag == 1){
            arr[count] = i;
            count = count+1;

        }//if
    }//for

    return 0;
}//main

// user-defined function to check prime number
int primeChecker(int n){
    int j, flag = 1;
    for(j = 2; j <= n / 2; ++j) {
        if(n % j == 0) {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }//if
    }//for
    return flag;
}//primeChecker
```